# Using a GET to POST data to a restfull api

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, web-services, grails

I'm trying to do `GET` that retrieves data from a URL and then a `POST` to a RESTful api.  The get call seems to work okay but the server sees nothing in the `file` parameter.  I have verified that the `GET` call is return pdf stream data and that it is placing it in the `FormData` arg.

Here is the complete call

```
function upload(key, url){

    var file;
    /* get data from url */
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType : 'text',
        contentType : 'application/pdf',
        success: function( data ) {
            file = data;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("error logging: "+  error);
        }
    });

    /* send data to api */
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("key", key);
    data.append("file", file); //<-- this has pdf stream data

    $.ajax({
        url: ROOT_URL + "/api/account/upload", 
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log("Uploaded!");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("error logging: "+  error);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
};
```

Here is the server side (grails + spring + jaxrs)

```
@POST
@Path('upload')
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces('application/json')
String upload(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
    GrailsWebRequest w = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()
    MultipartFile multipartFile = w.getRequest().getFile('file');

    println("request:" + request)
    println("multipartFile:" + multipartFile)
    println("parameterMap:" + w.getRequest().getParameterMap() )

    return ['okay':'uploaded'] as JSON
}
```

Which currently prints out:

```
request:org.grails.jaxrs.web.RequestWrapper@448593df
multipartFile:null
parameterMap:[file:[], key:[c07fc0974ebb4f3a8fc21e3d002152d4]]
```

Comment: looks like you're firing two calls immediately when you have dependency `file` in second call which has to be derived from 1st call. Like John suggested, do your second POST call in the success callback of 1st GET call :)

Comment: I've set async: false so it works sequently

Answer (score 2):

Looks like when the POST call is happening, the variable file doesn't have a value yet.  Since you are wanting everything after GET call to occur after the server has returned data, you should move that code into a separate function that is called upon success.

Comment: Like this answer says you will need to chain your POST Ajax call inside the GETZ success. It will be possible for those variables not to be set yet.

Comment: I'm using async: false so it should be fine

Comment: doing a console.log(file) after the GET shows the PDF stream

Comment: Your logic makes sense, but it's not how jquery works.  The POST call is being initialized with a null value for data, even though it's not being run until after data has a value.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee.. what does the `console.log()` say ?

Comment: It just shows up as '%PDF-1.3' followed by blob data.

Comment: Did you check in DevTools -> Network ? What does it show in post parameters ?